# Creating a set of static constant variables in c#

Tags: c#, static-classes

I am trying to make a set of variables that I can pass as method variable something like this

```
static class ListViewStates
{
    public const int ACCOUNTVIEW = 1;
    public const int LARGEIMAGEVIEW = 2;
    public const int INFOVIEW = 3;
}

class ListViewHandler
{
    public void SetListViewState(ListViewStates state)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    }
}
class main
{
    ListViewHandler listhndlr = new ListViewHandler();
    listhndlr.SetListViewState(ListViewStates.ACCOUNTVIEW);
}
```

What do I have to do with ListViewStates to make this work ?

I have looked around google but I can't seem to find the right search phrase to find an answer.

Comment: Looks like you might want to use an enum instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to Use `enum` instead of a seperate class. the definition for `enum`  will be as follows:

```
enum ListViewStates
{
    ACCOUNTVIEW = 1,
    LARGEIMAGEVIEW = 2,
    INFOVIEW = 3,
}
```

To access this you have to rewrite Method signature as like the following:

```
public void SetListViewState(ListViewStates state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case ListViewStates.ACCOUNTVIEW:
            break;
        case ListViewStates.LARGEIMAGEVIEW:
            break;
        case ListViewStates.INFOVIEW:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you want a `enum`, not a `static class`:

```
public enum ListViewStates
{
    ACCOUNTVIEW = 1,
    LARGEIMAGEVIEW = 2,
    INFOVIEW = 3
}
```